# How to Click on two elements simultaneously

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to click on different elements at the same time.
 sample code:-
    `

```
List<WebElement> labels = Webdriver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for(WebElement label : labels)
{
  if(label.getAttribute("title").equals("A"))
  {
    WebElement clickableA = label.findElement(By.tagName("div"));
    act.moveToElement(clickableA).moveByOffset(10,10).clickAndHold().build().perform();
  }
  if(label.getAttribute("title").equals("B"))
  {
    WebElement clickableB = label.findElement(By.tagName("B"));
    act.moveToElement(clickableB).moveByOffset(10,10).click().build().perform();
  }
}
`
```

When I iterate over the list, it give me elements one by one. So I m confused. So to click on A and B simultaneously if they gone display one after other.
Please help me

Comment: No, you can't click two elements simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

it seems a bit of a strange thing to want to do, to me at least. With selenium webdriver we can automate the actions we perform. Can you actually click on 2 different elements simultaneously by hand?

Anyway this code would iterate over all the items one by one, and perform (or not) some action one by one.